# " Select * From myTable WHERE $var='y' " Is this Possible?

Tags: mysql, select, checkbox

I'm trying to do the following as per the simpliest way

form

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Filter[Column1]" value="y" />
<input type="checkbox" name="Filter[Column2]" value="y" />
<input type="checkbox" name="Filter[Column3]" value="y" />
```

php

```
$filter=(Column1, Column2, Column3);
$post= ($_POST['Filter'][Column1], $_POST['Filter'][Column2], $_POST['Filter'][Column3]);
if(isset($post) && !empty($post)){
$query= "Select * From myTable WHERE $filter='y'";
}
```

Actually I need to filter rows based on checked checkboxes.
Does it make sense?

Comment: what is your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything seems fine to me except it seems unnecessary to declare $filter with all of the $_POST values just so you can test against that instead of just testing the post value.

Also, since you are looping through each filter and making a separate query for each, you are essentially pulling three separate results.  I don't know if that was the intended result, but if you wanted to actually test all three filters at once then you would need to put all the filters into a single WHERE condition that is joined by AND's or OR's

```
if(isset($_POST['Filter']) && !empty($_POST['Filter'])){
  $query = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE ";
  foreach( $_POST['Filter'] as $filter ){
    $query .= "$filter='y' AND ";
  }
  // Once we add our filters, strip off that last unnecessary ' AND ' from the query string.
  $query = substr($query, 0, -5);
```

Comment: $filter declares the column names of my table

Comment: Then that block of code should be more or less what you are looking for, possibly with modification to your specific needs

Comment: unknowen column y in where clause...maybe the form is not set properly?

Comment: <input type="checkbox" name="Filter[]" value="Column1" />...like this your code works like a charm. Thank you I had spent several hours on this

Answer (score 2):

This is very well possible. The variable `$filter` is subsituted in your SQL, so in this case it can perfectly be a column name.

Mind though, that you have to thoroughly check your input. If anyone was to post garbage to your script, the query could break, or they could even deliberately wreck your database or steal your information!.

Therefor, I would recommend building an array of allowed filters, and check the posted data against that array. If it's not in there, don't use it in your query.

And of course, think of a different variable name. Currently you are using `$filter` twice, which will probably cause problems. :)